# Updating array list in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-query

I want to update the Status field inside array list of Slots where id = "".

Sample data

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("621e816e7a938400016c5c64"),
  "Resource": "abc@gmail.com",
  "School": {
    "Class": [
      {
        "Type": "ABC",
        "Slots": [
          {
            "id": "",
            "Duration": "1 week",
            "Status": "Released",
            "Selected": true
          },
          {
            "id": "123",
            "Duration": "1 week",
            "Status": "Released",
            "Selected": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I am approaching:

```js
db.getCollection("XYZ").update({
  "Resource": "abc@gmail.com",
  "School.Class": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "Type": "ABC",
      "Slots.Status": "Released",
      "Slots.id": "",
      "Slots.Duration": "1 week"
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "School.Class.$[outer].Slots.$[inner].Status": "Confirmed"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "outer.Type": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "inner.Duration": "1 week"
    }
  ]
})
```

But it is updating the status as confirmed for the both the array list.How can I update the particular field where "Slots.id" : "" . Please forgive me in case of any misalignment or brackets missing in data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you are almost there, since you want to update only values where `id` is `""` you have to add that condition into `arrayFilters`: `"inner.id": ""`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "Resource": "abc@gmail.com",
  "School.Class": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "Type": "ABC",
      "Slots.Status": "Released",
      "Slots.id": "",
      "Slots.Duration": "1 week"
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "School.Class.$[outer].Slots.$[inner].Status": "Confirmed"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "outer.Type": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "inner.Duration": "1 week",
      "inner.id": ""  // <--- This line
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/93dtBMlN4QZ)